# Show the flagging reason in Triage

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage

In the Triage review queue, the reviewer is sometimes redirected to the question that has just been reviewed to allow for the reviewer to vote on the question, i.e. this screen:

[image: Screenshot of Triage review]

If a reviewer marks a question as unsalvageable, I'd like to be able to see their reason for doing so. Possibly when hovering over the **unsalvageable** text.

Comment: Isn't it the same reason every time? "Unsalvageable: this question has problems that cannot be fixed by editing and should be deleted."

Comment: @CodyGray Marking a question as **Unsalvageable** is equivalent to flagging it, I would like to see what the reviewer flagged it as.

Comment: @CodyGray: Duplicate is very different from spam.